# Eclipse Not Showing Changes

Tags: java

Okay to I pulled to code from https://bitbucket.org/satscape/sim-u-kraft/src using git into my eclipse src folder. Normally I hit refresh and boom the code is there. But when I tried it this time the files just don't show up. I tried refreshing and restarting eclipse/workspace

Comment: Have you tried a Project clean?

Comment: As @Austin suggests, try cleaning the project. Select Project > Clean. Then refresh

Comment: It still does not work, the new files and folders don't apper @Austin

Comment: Check the files using file explorer, is it there?

Comment: @JoelMin. yes Inside of the folder all the classes and folders exist